# Find first string and search for immediate second string and capture the version

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file xyz.txt and i want to find search first string and immediate occurrence of the second string and stop there  and extract version out of it using sed.

**xyz.txt**

```
    "com.abc.def:ghi": {
        "sometext1": [
            "blah bla1",
            "blah bla2",
            "blah bla3"
        ],
        "string1": "1.1.xyz"
    },
    "**first.string.def:ghi.jkl**": {
        "sometext2": [
            "blah bla4",
            "blah bla5",
            "blah bla6"
        ],
        "**string1**": "**1.2.3.4**"
    },
    "com.zbc.def:ghi.jklm": {
        "sometext3": [
            "blah bla9",
            "blah bla10",
            "blah bla11"
        ],
        "string1": "5.6.7.9"
    },
    "com.mbc.def:ghi.jkn": {
        "sometext4": [
            "blah bla1",
            "blah bla2",
            "blah bla3"
        ],
        "string1": "10.1.23"
    },


   ..... so on
```

I want to capture version that occurs first string (first.string.def:ghi.jkl) and second string (string1) and should provide me version number like 1.2.3.4

Comment: Is this is a JSON file? Why is this tagged under `bash`?

Comment: Can you show an example with real values for `first.string` and 2nd string?

Comment: Its not a json file. Its a simple text file. Example of first string is something like "com.android.myapp" second string is something like "linux"

Comment: Could you update the input string based on the above comment, and also show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I just tried using grep but I am a new bie so couldn't do it using sed.

Comment: that is okay, we were newbie too.. but on SO, we need to see your effort as well.. the command you tried with grep will do.. please click [edit] and add that to question..

Comment: grep -e com.first.string.def:ghi.jkl -e string1  xyz.txt



xyz.txt:            "string1": "1.1.xyz"
xyz.txt:        "first.string.def:ghi.jkl": {
xyz.txt:            "string1": "1.2.3.4"
xyz.txt:            "string1": "5.6.7.9"
... so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be done with GNU grep with options `-z` data line ends in 0 byte, `-P` PCRE, `-o` only matching.

```
grep -zPo '\Q"first.string.def:ghi.jkl"\E[^}]*\Q"string1":\E\s+"\K[^"]*'
```

regex may be improved depending actual sturcture

Comment: This doesnt give any output

Comment: using given file xyz.txt :`grep -zPo '\Q"**first.string.def:ghi.jkl**"\E[^}]*\Q"**string1**":\E\s+"\K[^"]*'  xyz.txt`

Comment: Another question on this: When i am using this within a script it throws an error saying unexpected char: '\'

sh(script: "grep -zPo '\Q"**first.string.def:ghi.jkl**"\E[^}]*\Q"**string1**":\E\s+"\K[^"]*' xyz.txt")

Comment: maybe because backslash must be escaped depending on language and string literals syntax

Comment: Do you know how can I do that for groovy ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed

```
sed '/first.string.def:ghi.jkl/,/string1/!d
/string1/!d
s///
s/[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/
' infile
```

Comment: I just tried something like this 

sed '/com.android.myapp/,/found/!d/found/!ds///s/[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/' xyz.txt 

but getting error as below :
sed: -e expression #1, char 58: extra characters after command

Comment: Try to record my answer in a file lescript.sh in the same directory. Adapt to your use android ... and replace infile by xyz.txt. chmod +x lescript.sh and run it ./lescript.sh. If you try in a one liner command, you must add ; after each !d and after s///. hope this help.